# How to pass a Javascript string to php on the same page

Tags: php, javascript, string

My page has a mix of Javascript and php. Javascript is used to select a string from several choices. Then some php code needs to do something with this string.

I have seen some examples that seem to be talking about passing variables across different web pages. I'm just doing this all on one page and all I'm trying to pass is a string.

I guess another solution would be to use php to select the string, if that's possible?

Comment: All you want to do is to pass a string from pageA to pageB?
You should try sending that string as a `part of the URL` or as a `POST request`, or in the worst case - `cookies`.

Comment: You probably get better answers if you explain what the string is for and what you want to do with it. Whether JS and PHP are on the same page does not matter. PHP is executed first, the result (text) is sent to the browser where it evaluates it as JavaScript and HTML.

Comment: The only way to pass a javascript variable to PHP is to send a POST or GET method to the php script, but this cannot be done without reloading the page. If you are doing this, you might as well just use PHP to take input from the form elemnts on your page `<?php $example=$_POST['example_form_name'];`. Otherwise you may need to describe your script in a little more detail.

Comment: JavaScript and PHP run in different contexts: PHP at your web server, and JavaScript at the browser. Communication between them involves a network, either HTTP or WebSockets.  Without knowing the nature of what you want to do it's hard to comment beyond that.

Comment: I'm not trying to pass a string across pages. I'm trying to pass a string that was retrieved through Javascript to php *in the same page*. In the original code the string is hardcoded. I'm just adding Javascript so that the string can be dynamically changed at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

By the time your browser renders the page, PHP has finished its job and closed the connection.

To pass some value determined on the client-side with js you need a new request. This means you need to use Ajax.

Comment: When he says "You'll need to make a request to the server via JavaScript", he means AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

PHP parses data server-side (**before** the page loads), whereas JavaScript handles everything browser-side (**after** or **on** page load).  You can't pass JavaScript into PHP functionality unless you use AJAX to send the PHP script a variable:

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">

<script type="text/javascript">
   // Find whatever string you need
   var something = $('.input').val();

   $(function() {
      $.ajax({
         url: '/path/to/php_script.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: 'variable='+something,
         success: function(data) {
            $('.display_div').html(data);
         }
      });
   });

</script>
```

**PHP**

```
$something = $_POST['variable'];

// Do something with it
echo strlen($something);
```

Comment: What is php_script.php? Is that the name of the page where all the code is located?

Comment: php_script.php is just a sample PHP file which I made up.  You need to put all your PHP which modifies your string in this separate file

Comment: So in your example, that PHP code goes inside that other file?

Comment: A good information also is that the above example uses the jquery framework which you must include before it will work.

Comment: What if I don't even need to modify the string? Do I still need an external file? In the original code the url is hardcoded into the php. I'm just using Javascript so that that url can be dynamically changed at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't need to specifically use any PHP functionality for manipulating your string, just stick to JavaScript and don't make any AJAX calls.  But you _need_ to use PHP, you're going to need to send it to an external PHP method and return it through AJAX.

Comment: So to get this string into the php in the same file, I would have to send the string to an external php file, and it would just send the string back so I can finally get it into the php section of my code?

Comment: It seems kind of like a waste to have to pass this string to an external php file just to read it back, know what I mean?

Comment: It's not a waste. PHP by its very definition is a Hypertext PRE-processor. It processes everything BEFORE page load. If you want to get PHP to manipulate JavaScript data (i.e. things which have been created or modified AFTER page load), you're going to need to send this data to the server to be PRE-processed by PHP. So you'll need to send it to an external PHP file.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make a request to the server via JavaScript, since PHP is a server-side language.  You could use a POST or GET variable to send the string to the same page and then add PHP code to check for that variable when the page is loaded.

The PHP would be something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['string'])) {
// do something with the string
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't use Ajax?

Comment: You could do it either way, a page reload or via AJAX.  Although if you do it with AJAX you might want to separate the PHP code that handles the string just for clarity.